# How to detect XSS vulnerability for any commits in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: security, gitlab, gitlab-ci, xss, owasp

There should be a gitlab CI/CD task runs for every commit. The task is to detect XSS vulnerability for all the commits getting in the pipeline. Suppose if there is an XSS threat found in commits means the pipeline should fail with a reason.

Is this feasible to do that ?

Is there any generic security library in javascript or python to detect the XSS threat (stated by OWASP guideline) in gitlab CI/CD ?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to scan *all* commits, [GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#secret-detection-scans-all-commits-in-merge-requests) (February 2023) proposes:

> ### Secret Detection scans all commits in merge requests
>
> Due to technical limitations, GitLab Secret Detection previously scanned only the latest commit on branch pipelines.
>
> Now, when Secret Detection runs in a [merge request (MR) pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html), it **scans all of the MR’s commits** so you can catch leaks made in earlier commits.
>
> This improvement builds on recently-added support for [security scanning in MR pipelines](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#run-security-scanning-tools-in-merge-request-pipelines), so it’s only available in the Latest version of the Secret Detection CI/CD template, not the Stable version.
>
> You can enable this new feature now by [switching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/#use-security-scanning-tools-with-merge-request-pipelines) to the Latest version of the Secret Detection CI/CD template.
> We plan to update the Stable templates with this change in GitLab 16.0.
>
> Note that Latest templates can receive breaking changes in any release.
> To learn more about Stable and Latest templates, see documentation on [CI/CD template versioning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html#versioning).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/372262).

Answer (score 0):

The ZAP packaged fullscan will do this: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/full-scan/

That scans for lots of other vulnerabilities as well but you can tune it to just look for XSSs.

FYI the GitLab pro option also uses ZAP for DAST scanning.